# UITableView is revealed only after it is scrolled upwards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a storyboard with a UIView and a UITableView in it. The UITableView has custom cells (UITableViewCell with xib).
When I run the app, only the first row of the table is shown, the rest of the table is hidden. 
The rows are not seen on the screen, but they respond to user interaction as expected.

The rest of the cells are revealed only after the table is scrolled upwards.

What could be the problem?

Here is the code for UIView with the table:

```
@implementation EldersTableViewController
@synthesize items;
@synthesize tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    EldersDataHendler *edh = [[EldersDataHendler alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *itemsFromPList = [edh dataForTableFrom:[NSDictionary         dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"eldersData"     ofType:@"plist"]]];
    self.items = itemsFromPList;
    [edh release];
    edh=nil;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}


- (IBAction)didPressBackButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return [self.items  count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

    SEObject *cellInfo = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    EldersItemCell* cell = (EldersItemCell*)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EldersItemCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EldersItemCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id obj in topObjects){
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[EldersItemCell class]]){
                cell = (EldersItemCell*)obj;
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    [cell setObject:cellInfo];
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SEObject *cellInfo = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    if (!eldersDetailsViewController){
        eldersDetailsViewController = [[self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"elderDetailsVC"] retain];
    }
    eldersDetailsViewController.seObject = cellInfo;
    [self.view addSubview:eldersDetailsViewController.view];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [eldersDetailsViewController release];
    [tableView release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Thanks in advance,
Luda

Comment: UITableView may not be everyone's cup of tea, but surely not reviled?! ;) I suspect your cells are not "revealed".

Comment: What happens when you use the standard canonical code for cellForRowAtIndexPath using standard UITableCells rather that your custom views? It's just a way of eliminating whether the issue is with EldersItemCell or with your Storyboard.

Comment: No not reviled :), just not revealed :)
You are right! The problem must be with the custom cell, because the standard UITableCells shows fine.

Comment: Problem solved!
Thanks a lot dear arooaroo. There was something with the custom cell with the xib. So I've created a custom Table View Cell programmatically. Here is a nice tutorial:
http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html

Comment: @Luda, just in case you're interested (since there are no direct messages here that I know of): the LinkedIn link in your profile is broken.

Comment: @FreeNickname, Thanks :) I'll fix it

Comment: @Luda, you're welcome :) I'm not a recruiter or anything, I was just curious :)

Comment: @FreeNickname, you are welcome to connect :)

Comment: @Luda, thanks) I don't have a real account there at the moment though, so it will have to wait)

Comment: @FreeNickname no prob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Thanks a lot dear arooaroo. There was something with the custom cell with the xib. So I've created a custom Table View Cell programmatically. Here is a nice [tutorial](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

Answer (score 0):

1st just create an object class for your cell design,then import it in your .m file.then try like this and connect the table view delegate and data source properly

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Displayfriendscell";
Displayfriendscell *cell = (Displayfriendscell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[Displayfriendscell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                  }
// Configure the cell...
[[cell viewWithTag:121] removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:151] removeFromSuperview];
friend *user = [sortedFriendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    
//cell.nameLabel.text = user.contactNAame;
cell.nameLabel.text = user.friendName;
//cell.nameLabel.text =[[sortedFriendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
//user.friendName=[[sortedFriendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];  
NSLog(@"name is%@",cell.nameLabel.text);

return cell;

}
```